# how to use Construct 3 object with ReactJs

Tags: html, reactjs, game-development, construct-2, construct-3

So i'm familiar with Construct 3 platform, and i want to do website development. I want a character like object for my web that can move like game character. I know how to make this in Construct 3, but i don't know how to achieve this with React. I try to do some research, but i don't find any way to do this. I noticed that Construct 3 produce HTML5 game which is suitable for web. I've tried to exported my project as HTML5 type, but it came as a bunch of code, and i don't know how to include it to my React project

I wonder if there is some way to take my character and put it in some part of my ReactJs project?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: what i want is a way to use my object (let say my sprite) from Construct3 and put it in some part of my React project, i don't want to post the whole Construct 3 project.

Answer (score 1):

Construct projects are based on HTML5, which makes them perfectly suited for web publishing. This guide includes some useful information to know when publishing Construct games online. https://www.construct.net/en/tutorials/publishing-web-10

Comment: i don't need to post the whole project to server, i want to use some of it's part and continue developing with React, cause it's better for web

Comment: Please be more specific for the question, like code samples etc, linking to another website, maybe too generic.